# Different menu for different tabs in tab+swipe application for android project

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, swipe, android-menu

I am a beginner to android applications and java, basically I am a PHP developer.

I've a project for a tab+swipe application,

### ***Reseller.java***

```
package com.idevoc.onsitereseller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

public class Reseller extends FragmentActivity {

    FragmentTransaction transaction;
    static ViewPager mViewPager;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reseller);

    Fragment tabOneFragment = new TabOne();
    Fragment tabTwoFragment = new TabTwo();

    PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPagerAdapter.addFragment(tabOneFragment);
    mPagerAdapter.addFragment(tabTwoFragment);

    //transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
            mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(
                new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        // When swiping between pages, select the
                        // corresponding tab.
                        getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                    }
                });

    ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    Tab tab1 = ab.newTab().setText("Tab One")
                    .setTabListener(new TabListener<TabOne>(
                    this, "tabone", TabOne.class));

            Tab tab2 = ab.newTab().setText("Tab Two")
                            .setTabListener(new TabListener<TabTwo>(
                    this, "tabtwo", TabTwo.class));

            ab.addTab(tab1);
            ab.addTab(tab2);         
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

public static class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private Fragment mFragment;
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;

    /** Constructor used each time a new tab is created.
      * @param activity  The host Activity, used to instantiate the fragment
      * @param tag  The identifier tag for the fragment
      * @param clz  The fragment's Class, used to instantiate the fragment
      */
    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
    }

    /* The following are each of the ActionBar.TabListener callbacks */

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // Check if the fragment is already initialized
        if (mFragment == null) {
            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
            ft.attach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null) {
            // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // User selected the already selected tab. Usually do nothing.
    }

            public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0,
                            android.app.FragmentTransaction arg1)
            {


            }

            public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, android.app.FragmentTransaction arg1)
            {

                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(arg0.getPosition());
            }

            public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0,
                            android.app.FragmentTransaction arg1)
            {


            }
}

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    private final ArrayList<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager){
        super(manager);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment){
        mFragments.add(fragment);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }
  }

 }
```

### ***TabOne.java***

```
 package com.idevoc.onsitereseller;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class TabOne extends Fragment
{
public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
     @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_a, container, false);
            return view;
    }

}
```

### ***TabTwo.java***

```
 package com.idevoc.onsitereseller;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;

 public class TabTwo extends Fragment
 {

     @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_a, container, false);

            return view;
    }
  }
```

Here I am loading two tabs for the application and loading a common menu, but I need to load a different menu for different tabs like:

if the tab is TabOne then load menu_a, if tab is TabTwo then load menu_b with different options.
I don't want to load the common menu.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

create a menu xml file for menu_a.xml and menu_b.xml in the res/menu folder.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_item_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="@string/description_search"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_share"
        android:title="@string/description_share"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

To create a option menu for the current Fragment displayed, add setHasOptionsMenu(true); to  the Fragment onCreate() method.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

}
```

Then you must inflate the corresponding option menu (menu_a.xml or menu_b.xml) by override the onCreateOptionsMenu() method.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_a, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

For handling menu selections override the onOptionsItemSelected()

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_item_search:                
              //do something
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_item_share:
              //do something
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

see Creating an Options Menu: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html for more details.

Comment: how to do this with effects?

Comment: @bernzkie what kind of effects?

Comment: like the first menu icon will fadeOut then the second will fadeIn? maybe if only possible?

Comment: @bernzkie if so I would have tried adding the menu items in the parent activity, kept a reference to the menu item and programatically switched the menu icon in a tab or page change listener.  This could help http://stackoverflow.com/a/34295265/546054

Comment: doing this append items in the menu. is it possible to completely replace the items

Comment: @Saifee make sure you only inflate the Fragment specific menu.xml.  and do not inflate any menu in the parent Activity. If you do that the Fragment menu will be added to you Activity menu.

Comment: The items are shown, but the `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` does nothing in `FragmentTwo`. Why? I have a menu implemented in `MainActivity` and another menu implemented in `FragmentTwo`. The `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)` in `FragmentTwo` has `menu.clear()` and only the options for `FragmentTwo` are shown.

Comment: I fond the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19449914/4300670. The magic happens in the `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` in `MainActivity`. It must `return false`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I got the output with these codes ,

In TabOne.java and TabTwo.java I've added

```
   setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

In onCreateView() function and after that menu function with different menu,removed menu function from main class.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_a, container, false);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
         inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_b, menu);
    }
```