# Fragment's onOptionsItemSelected doesn't get called

Tags: android, android-fragments

My fragment replaces the parent Activity options with a specific option item but when I click on the item, only activity's `onOptionItemSelected` gets called eventhough I've overridden the method inside Fragment. Am I missing something?

**Fragment's methods:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    Log.d(TAG, "Fragment.onCreateOptionsMenu");

    if (mPasteMode) {
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.contexual_paste, menu);
        getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("PasteMode");
    }
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    Log.d(TAG, "Fragment.onOptionsItemSelected");

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.context_action_paste:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                     "It worked ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Activity's methods:**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    Log.d(TAG, "MainActivitiy.onOptionsItemSelected");
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_refresh:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Action Refresh selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Logcat output:**

```
MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu
Fragment.onCreateOptionsMenu
MainActivitiy.onOptionsItemSelected
```

So how can I have the `onOptionsItemSelected` of the fragment called?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You are not chaining to the superclass in the activity methods. Please have `onCreateOptionsMenu()` return `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)`, and have `onOptionsItemSelected()` return `super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)` (except for the item that you are handling, which should return `true` to indicate that you have handled the event).

Comment: It should be noted that setHasOptionsMenu(true) must have been called in the fragment for  is

Answer (score 64):

If your Activity's **onOptionsItemSelected** method **returs true**, ***the call is consumed in activity and Fragment's onOptionsItemSelected is not called.*** 
So, **return false in your Activity onOptionsItemSelected method** or parent class implementation via super.onOptionsItemSelected call (default implementation returns false).

According Activity class javadoc, method Activity.onOptionsItemSelected should:

> Return false to allow normal menu processing to proceed, true to consume it here

Comment: Thank you very much you saved my time.

Comment: You are completely right! Just make the `onOptionsItemSelected` `return false` in `MainActivity` and all will work as expected.

Answer (score 17):

In my case I did not add any menu items (i.e. I did not call `onCreateOptionsMenu` in either the activity or the fragment). However, I needed to use the action bar home (up) button in the fragment. For this I had to make sure  that `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` was called in the fragment's `onCreateView()` method before this could work. Then I didn't need an `onOptionsItemSelected` override in my activity.

Comment: setHasOptionsMenu(true) was the fix, thx.

Answer (score 5):

After a few hours of working on this issue, I found a solution.

You need to call onOptionsItemSelected in **activity** but return false like this

```html
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return false
    }
```

Next step is adding **setHasOptionsMenu(true)** inside **fragment onCreate()**

And finally you can call onOptionsItemSelected in your fragment and handle menu item click

```html
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        //My awesome stuff
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution i.e

Fragment.class

```
 @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // Do something that differs the Activity's menu here
    //MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.wifinity_setting, menu);
    for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
        MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
        SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(menu.getItem(i).getTitle().toString());
        spanString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 0, spanString.length(), 0); //fix the color to white
        item.setTitle(spanString);
    }
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.menu1:
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(context, activity.class);
            startActivity(intent3);
            return true;

    }
    return true;
}
```

ACtivity.class

overide the onOptionsItemSelected() 
// fragmnets onOptionselected method get called ..
this solution works for me

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        default:
            if(fragment != null)
                fragment.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the currently accepted solution, but another possible cause is having an ambiguous class reference.  I had a custom class in my project named MenuItem and my Fragment was interpreting that custom.MenuItem as the parameter type instead of android.view.MenuItem

The symptoms were a wiggly red underline on my Override and IDE message indicating that onOptionsItemSelected will not be called.

Answer (score 0):

```
if you are using view binding in your fragment you can populate menu using below code 

in your onCreate method use 

step 1 setHasOptionsMenu(true)
step 2 inflate menu by like below binding.actionBar.toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.home_screen_menu)

step 3 binding.actionBar.toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
            onOptionsItemSelected(it)
        }

then override 
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
           case 1{}
           case 2{}
    }
```