# Two searchviews showed up when switching tabs

Tags: android, searchview

Hi i am trying to add "search" functionality to my multiple tabs fragment. it is working fine with one tab, i am able to search and filter data no problem. So i use the same code for my other tabs, however, now the action bar show two search icon instead of one. I tried many different ways by hiding the searchview during detach/ attach action when switching tab, but still two search icons still pop up. One of the search icon will work for my current tab, and the other does not.

[image]

here is my code:

upcoming_event_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_upcoming_event_search"
        android:title="search event"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

past_event_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_past_event_search"
        android:title="search event"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

fragment 1:

```
public class EventTabUpcoming extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_tab_upcoming, container, false);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.listUpcomingEvent);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));

    recyclerView.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.upcoming_event_menu, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_upcoming_event_search);

    searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String searchText) {
    Log.d(logTag, "EventTabUpcoming -> onQueryTextChange w/ searchText: " + searchText);
    for (Section section : sectionAdapter.getCopyOfSectionsMap().values()) {
        if (section instanceof FilterableEventSection) {
            ((FilterableEventSection) section).filter(searchText);
        }
    }

    sectionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    Log.d(logTag, "onDetach is called");

    if (searchView != null) {
        searchView.clearFocus();
        searchView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    Log.d(logTag, "onAttach is called");

    if (searchView != null) {
        searchView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


}
```

Fragment 2 is a cloned from Fragment 1 except the view is now:

```
final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_tab_past, container, false);
```

and menu is

```
inflater.inflate(R.menu.past_event_menu, menu);
```

Please let me know how should i correct this problem.

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/14019740/1318946

Comment: the solution there does not work for searchView

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

Instead of inflate the menu in both tab's activities, i inflate the menu in the viewpager activity only, and in each tab fragment's onCreateOptionMenu, i get the searchview and setQueryTextListener.

ViewPager activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    /**
     * Inflate menu with searchview item
     */
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.event_menu, menu);
}
```

Tab 1

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    # get the searchview and set listener
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_event_search);
    searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
}
```

Tab 2

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    # get the searchview and set listener
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_event_search);
    searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
}
```